# Determining the relationship between Richard Holmes and Thomas Holme?

Tags: 19th-century, england, lancashire

I am a member of Ancestry.com, and I tested my DNA there. As a result, I found that I have a blood relationship with a person called John Holme. He was born in Croston, Lancashire in 1754. His father was Richard Holmes.

I examined my great grandfather in Japan and found a candidate. His name is Cecil Zohrab Ede. His mother's name is Helen Ede. Her maiden name is Helen Holme. She was born in Strand, Lancashire in 1835. Her father is Thomas Holme.

If Thomas Holme and Richard Holmes share a blood relationship, I think that I would be able to conclude that my great-grandfather was Cecil Zohrab Ede. However, I cannot find any historical documents showing that relationship.

How can I determine the relationship between Thomas Holme and Richard Holmes?

Comment: Some questions -- what range (e.g.3rd cousin - 5th cousins) has Ancestry suggested for the link to you and the related individual? What certainty level? And how do you know that you have a relationship with John Holme from the resukts?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to apply standard genealogical techniques to trace ancestry of Thomas Holme, starting with his parents and moving backwards. Be aware that the linkage might not be direct descendancy (i.e. Thomas might not be a direct descendant of Richard; they might both be descendants of another Holmes further up the line.)

You may also consider uploading your Ancestry DNAdata to [GedMatch](https://www.gedmatch.com) which is a site that allows you to look for matches to users who have tested at other sites; the more matches you find that link back to the Holme line (or indeed to the Ede line) the more confidence you can have in your identification.  But to be certain, you will always need to put in the hard work to trace the chain all the way back.

Comment: Could you expand on what you are referring to by applying "standard genealogical techniques"? As stated in the question, Akira is having trouble finding historical documents showing the relationship, which suggests he is already attempting this but is stuck

Comment: @HarryVervet do you really want an answer that covers the whole technique of  genealogical research? Akira's previous questions reveal that he understands the basic -- If he comes back and asks for more detail, I shall update.